# How can I make a random function generate a specific integer more often without using arrays and vector?

Tags: c++, board-game

I was making a ludo game and there's a rule that your pieces will only open when the 6 will shows up on a dice.

How can I make my dice generate the number 6 more often, without using arrays or vectors? I'm using c++.

Comment: Why the "without using arrays and vector" constraint?

Answer (score 5):

Generate a random number between 1 and some number higher than 6 (7, 8, 9, etc).  If the result is higher than 6 treat it as a 6.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that came up on my mind without using array is re-generating a random number again if it is not 6. You can arrange chances with iteration over re-generation.

But this solution does not perform well if random generation function costs high.